# Rustup is not recognised but rustic —version works

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

48.0 (MSVC shell)

I can run `rustc —version`

But `rustup` gives me `rustup is not recognised as an internal or external command`

Completely new to Rust world
And very poor knowledge of build tools currently

Can someone guide me as to what I should do
I have limited access to software which can be installed in my machine

Note: `cargo —version` also works

Answer (score 1):

[Rustup](https://www.rustup.rs) is just a toolchain manager, used to install different versions of Rust. So my guess is that you have installed Rust but havent installed rustup, as they are separate things.

You probably need to [install rustup](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#other-ways-to-install-rustup) separately on your system.

I would recommend that you use [cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html) to build rust code. It is included with most installations of Rust and it is the recommended and most common way of managing and building Rust projects.

Basic usage of cargo:

```
cargo new <project_name>

cd <project_name>

cargo build 

cargo run
```

Since you are a beginner, I strongly recommend that you read [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html) to get a decent start with the language.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might have downloaded a [standalone installer](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#standalone-installers) as opposed to [rustup itself](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#other-ways-to-install-rustup). It is possible to use Rust without rustup, but if you want to manage your toolchains with rustup, you'll want to uninstall Rust and run `rustup-init.exe`.